# Java CSON parser?

Tags: java, json, cson

Is there already a CSON parser for Java? JSON is very difficult to hand-write (which I will be doing a lot of for this project) and I would rather not make my own CSON parser.

If not, is there another easy-to-use alternative to JSON that there is Java support for? The major reason I would like to avoid JSON is that I will be dealing with rather large multiline strings.

EDIT: I am referring to [CoffeeScript Object Notation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-basics), not [Cursive Script Object Notation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-basics).

Answer (score 0):

[YAML](http://yaml.org/) is supported by a ton of languages [including Java](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-basics) and is very friendly with multiline strings.